# How to override three finger accessibility zoom gesture?

Tags: ios, accessibility

I am trying to create a gesture recognizer that responds to three touches, but the gesture is ignored if the user has the accessibility zoom feature enabled, which triggers off a three finger double tap.

My view uses massive UI elements, so zooming is not appropriate.  Is there an api to disable the accessibility zoom so I can respond to a three finger tap?

Comment: As a side question, I'm curious why you think zooming is not appropriate.  How can you tell whether someone really needs to zoom or not, no matter how "massive" your UI elements are?  I use zooming all the time and am not sure I'd like an app that disables it.  It frustrates me immensely when I find websites that have pinch/zoom disabled.

Comment: [The view](http://www.izaaklauer.com/s/Default-LifeTotal-tnhs.png) consists of two 200 pt numbers and a single button centered on the screen.  I am assuming that most users with zoom enabled will find my three finger gesture more useful in this view, but I appreciate that it would be frustrating for a user to attempt a zoom and have it fail.

Comment: Don't forget, that while users may not want to zoom in your app.  They may have to zoom on the launcher to launch your app... and need to unzoom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try posting a `UIAccessibilityPauseAssistiveTechnologyNotification` though I believe this only refers to external ATs, and not to VoiceOver and Zoom features.  Though I have not played around with it much.

EDIT: I just checked, the constant for disabling the zoom feature is not available in `UIAccessibilityConstants.h`.  So this will not work, meaning there is no viable solution for this.